# How can I stop Angular @ViewChild() from making new component instances?

Tags: angular, oop, raphael

I would like my parent component to execute methods in a child component (drawing component, which attaches a RaphaelJS object to a container). However, I keep getting browser errors, saying that the object hasn't been instantiated. Moving the method call to the child class eliminates the error, which seems to suggest that the component is being re-instantiated by the @ViewChild() in the parent class.

I'd like the parent to call drawing methods in the child, and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this. Some ideas that I've come up with are:

- Implement the child class as a service
- Create a non-Angular-ee static class or singleton and just call into that
- Redo the child class to store all its objects in a service & redraw all of that on every ngOnInit()

Comment: Cam you add some code?

Comment: Good question, but I was able to come up with my own solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by moving my Raphael initialization to the ngOnInit() method and then moving my @ViewChild() call in the parent component to the ngAfterViewInit() method. This way, the child component will have enough time to fully initialize and its Raphael object generated before the parent starts calling drawing methods in the child which require Raphael.

Child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-g-view',
    template:  
        `<div 
        id="conP" 
        class="container-fluid" 
        style="width:600px;height:600px;"
        >
        </div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./gview.component.css']
})
export class GVComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

    private paper: Raphael;

    constructor() {}

ngOnInit()  {
    this.paper = Raphael("conP", "100%", "100%");
    console.log(this.paper);
    let border = this.paper.rect(0,0,"100%","100%");
    border.attr({fill:"white"});
    console.log(border);
    }
```

Parent Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-par',
  templateUrl: './par.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./par.component.css'],
})
export class ParComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(GVComponent) _gv: GVComponent; 

  constructor(){}

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(`testing child component after init: ${this._gv}`);
    this._gv.testMethod();
}
```